# JavaScript get request HTML return

Tags: javascript, html

I've just started doing JavaScript so don't know any terminology really.

I am creating a google chrome extension, and the website it is on does not have an API, therefore I cannot get the data needed from it. I noticed if I just do a `GET request` on postman with the URL where the data is, I am returned the `HTML`, from which I can then parse the data and format it. Is this something that you can do in JavaScript, and if so could someone give me a brief overview/what to look at online?

The API request I am trying to make it to another page on the site with the relevant data for that specific search, but I have to remain on the page the user is.

So the user is on `page A`, and the related `page B` has the data that I need to display on page A without the user being redirected.

Comment: It's called web scraping, you can do it in javascript. If you want to do it in the browser you might need a proxy

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I did think this, however I would have to be on the webpage, and this API request that I am trying to make it to another page on the site with the relevant data for that specific search, so I do not think this would work for this use case

Comment: I don 't get it

Comment: @user18580816, konrad is correct, look up fetch in javascript.

Comment: So the user is on page A, and the related page B has the data that I need to display on page A without the user being redirected. I am overlaying data on top of a page a user visits, but since there is no API I have to make this request to HTML. @imvain2 therefore web scraping wouldn't work as I am not scraping information on the current user page. The information is coming from a separate page but the user cannot be redirected or move pages

Comment: @user18580816 you are misunderstanding the term web scraping. It just means to scrape content from a web page. You can be on page A, use javascript FETCH to call page B and scrape the content from that page and show on page A without the user being redirected.

Comment: Yet, if page B is on a different website from A then the browser will most likely block the request.

Comment: @Yogi No, I can get the HTML, have figured it out, now just trying to get it so I can access the result globally but not sure if that is a thing

Comment: @imvain2 ahhh yes, that was me being stupid my apologies. That is exactly what I am trying to do, just currently trying to figure out how to use this resolved promise outside of the fetch call